# error in import z3

Tags: python, z3

I am trying to use z3 in pydev, I add the path of z3py and libz3.dll to window/preferences/pydev/jython-interpreter, but i got the error as the following

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\linda\workspace\LearningPyDev\main.py", line 11, in 
    import z3
  File "C:\Users\linda\z3\python\z3.py", line 45, in 
    from z3printer import *
  File "C:\Users\linda\z3\python\z3printer.py", line 8, in 
    import sys, io, z3
ImportError: No module named io

What is the io module anyway? Is it possible to run z3 in pydev?

Comment: `io` is a python module.

Answer (score 1):

`io` is a core Python module. It was added in 2.6 and has been present in every subsequent version. Are you on a very old version of Python? If you're running Python version 2.5 or earlier (you can check with `python --version` in any commandline), you'll need to update Python to a newer version.